# ruby regex for validating and parsing "1,a|2,b|3,c" string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am in a search of one regular expression which validates the following string format "1,a|2,b|3,c".

Also I want to parse this string and extract out the numbers and characters.

Can any one has any idea on what could be the best regular expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression: http://regex101.com/r/qI7kW9

`/(\d),([a-z])(?:\||$)/gi`

The first capturing group will hold the digit, the second will hold the letter. If there will be more than one character that you want to capture, use this:

`/(\d+),([a-z]+)(?:\||$)/gi`

Comment: Thanks for the regex, while trying I am getting the following error
gunknown regexp option - g
This seems to be ruby version error, can it be done without g or global option I mean is there any alternative for putting global

Comment: This is the output from console
jruby-1.6.7.2 :021 > "1,a|2,b|3,c".match(/(\d),([a-z])(?:\||$)/gi)
SyntaxError: (irb):21: gunknown regexp option - g

Comment: Ruby might be global by default, try without it.

Comment: It is now working with ruby scan method, I tried this and it worked for me instead of g option
""1,a|2,b|3,c".scan(/(\d+),([a-z]+)(?:\||$)/i)
Thank you very much for your quick and accurate reply.

Comment: You're very welcome. Please accept the answer if it was useful to you,  @Dinesh.

Comment: Hi,
As the above solution very well work for me, but now I want to try reg exp (/(\d+),([a-z]+)(?:\||$)/i) while validating this string>

As before that I use ruby Steing#scan method to scan the string, but this time I want to validate if user has entered the string in this format ("1,a|2,b|3,c").

So for this I am trying to do the following approach

jruby-1.6.7.2 :022 > "1,a|2,b|3,c" =~ /(\d+),([a-z]+)(?:\||$)/i
 => 0 

As you can see it returns 0 but even if you modify the string and put it in the wrong way you will still get 0.

Any solution to the above problem??

Comment: Try http://regex101.com/r/uO7tG2

Comment: Thanks again, this works perfectly for my case now. Thank you once again.